# Wireless to Wired Bridge with Bonjour Service Clients

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, bonjour

I want to create a wireless to wired bridge on my rasbian powered Rasperry Pi to connect my DVB-T box to the network. The DVB-T box sends the signal into the network using Apple's bonjour service.

To create the bridge I followed [this tutorial](http://rbnrpi.wordpress.com/wifi-to-ethernet-adapter-for-an-ethernet-ready-tv/) which it works as intended. If I connect my PC with the Raspberry via LAN I am able to access other devices in the Wifi network and, of course, the internet. Additionally I can see and ping the PC from other clients in the Wifi network.

When I connect the DVB-T device, nothing works. As far as I can tell it gets an IP via the DHCP on the Raspbian and I can ping it from there, but it does not appear anywhere in the Wifi network. I already tried different configurations on the DVB-T device, static IP instead of DHCP with the main network's router as DNS server - no difference.

Right now I have no idea what else I could do. Could it be possible that the Bonjour service of the DVB-T device has only impact in the range of the Rasbian's DHCP (in the LAN network)? If so, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Bonjour service provider doesn't reside in the same subnet as the other devices then they won't be able to see the traffic.

The router would have to be configured to allow multicasting or broadcasting across subnets.

There also exist Bonjour gateways that bridge traffic across subnets/VLANs, one such is from [Aerohive](http://info.aerohive.com/Free-Bonjour-Gateway-Info.html?source=website), although I think that would be overkill here.

If you wish to research further, you should look up "Bonjour Multiple Subnets", "mDNS" and "DNS-SD".